# Integrate the differentials

Tags: calculus, integration

To simplify the integral I was thinking about using FTOC2 but is it supposed to be as f(t) because here it says $ln(x^2+1)$ I was confused where does it have to be as $ln(t^2+1)$ to use FTOC2 or can we simply says hat it is equal to $ln(x^2+1)$ ?

${\Large\int} _{-2}^{x} \dfrac{d}{dx}ln(x^2+1)dx$

Comment: No, there is some confusion. The $x$ outside and the $x$ inside are clearly different, because the one inside is the variable of integration. You can change every $x$ inside the integration to $t$ to get $\int_{-2}^x \frac{d}{dt}\ln(t^2+1) dt$

Answer (score 2):

It's equal to $\int^x_{-2} \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt = ln(t^2+1) \Biggr|_{-2}^x.$